# Don't allow docker internet access

Tags: networking, iptables, docker

I'm looking for a simple way to limit my docker containers so they only have local access and not internet access.

I've tried using IPtables to do this and the following works:

```
iptables -I FORWARD -i docker0  -j DROP
```

but if the docker service is restarted localhost can no longer access the containers.

Comment: What distro do you use?

Answer (score 4):

I assume by "local access" you mean you want containers to be able to talk to each other and the docker host, but not be able to get to the network outside the docker host ?

You have a couple of options.

1.

Use iptables to drop all packets to/from your external
network interface in the DOCKER chain.

```
iptables -I DOCKER -i eno1 -j DROP
```

(`eno1` might be different in your case; it's the name of the network interface on my docker host.)

2.

Turn off **ip forwarding** on the docker host.

```
echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

Note: this will also restrict any virtual machines in the same way but
is the general and safe approach for the more security conscious.

SOURCE:

See https://docs.docker.com/v1.5/articles/networking/#the-world
"Communication between containers and the wider world" for more information.